# SQL Combine Select, Update and Join into one query

Tags: mysql

I'm a beginner in sql and I am doing this through a php document. I need to know how to combine these into one query. The sql is rough but hopefully you all should get the idea of what I'm trying to do.

**What I'm trying to do is join the 'username' in the 'stats' and 'ufc133' tables 
then update the 'scores' table based on the value stored in 'pick1' from the 'ufc133' table

**This is code for a sports picks website and my goal with this query is to give users scores based on the right or wrong picks they make. The scores and picks are stored in different tables. This particular query is just for 'pick1'**

The Code:

```
<?php

mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM ufc133, stats JOIN stats ON ufc133.username = stats.username 
UPDATE stats SET score = (score + 10), mmascore = (mmascore + 10), mmawins = (mmawins + 1), mmagames = (mmagames + 1), wins = (wins + 1), games = (games + 1)
WHERE pick1 = 11
");

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updates statements can only reference one table. Your update can contain a *subselect* in the WHERE clause to match the ID of the rows you want to update with the result of some query. For example:

```
UPDATE stats
SET score = (score + 10), mmascore = (mmascore + 10), mmawins = (mmawins + 1), mmagames = (mmagames + 1), wins = (wins + 1), games = (games + 1)
-- This part made up for illustration purposes
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT Table1.id from Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.id WHERE....
)
```

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I tried your solution. It doesn't have errors but for whatever reason I can't get it to work how I want it. Here is exactly what I put---- mysql_query("
UPDATE stats
SET score = (score + 10), mmascore = (mmascore + 10), mmawins = (mmawins + 1), mmagames = (mmagames + 1), wins = (wins + 1), games = (games + 1)

WHERE username IN (
    SELECT stats.username from stats INNER JOIN ufc133 ON stats.username = ufc133.username WHERE pick1 = 11
)
");

Comment: We'll need more info to keep helping. What results do you get? What are you expecting? Describing your tables and relationships might be helpful, too. INNER JOINs and WHERE clauses can get tricky. You also might find it easier to test and debug if you work your query out in a tool like MySQL Workbench or SQuirreL before plugging it into your PHP code. I'd also recommend breaking the update into pieces -- work on the subselect as a standalone query until you get the right results, then work on the update.

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out all it took was an UPDATE statement. There was a little more to it than the simple ones I'm used to using. Here it is. ----------------- mysql_query("
UPDATE stats, ufc133
SET score = (score + 10), mmascore = (mmascore + 10), mmawins = (mmawins + 1), mmagames = (mmagames + 1), wins = (wins + 1), games = (games + 1)
WHERE stats.username = ufc133.username
AND ufc133.pick1 = 11
");

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send separate/multiple statements via [`mysql_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database

You're going to have to issue multiple commands, or call a stored procedure.